# How to add an item if not already present in a list?

Tags: regex, ansible

I try to add a path to a comma separated list of paths in a text file via Ansible.

My text file have (or not) a property `paths` which contains a list of path. i.e. paths = path1, path2 , path3
I want to be sure that a path (pathX) is present in the list, whatever its position and add it to the end if not (or create a new line paths = pathX if no line)

I have tried without success the lineinfile module with a regexp negative lookahead

```
    lineinfile:
      path: /myfile
      state: present
      regexp: '^(paths =([\s,]+(?!pathX)[\w=\/\-\."]+)*)([\s,]*[\w=\/\-\."]+)*$'
      line: '\1\3, pathX'
      backrefs: yes
```

when paths is not present, i want to insert `paths = pathX`
when `paths = path1`, i want to have `paths = path1, pathX`
when `paths = path1, pathX`, i want to have `paths = path1, pathX`
when `paths = pathX, path1`, i want to have `paths = pathX, path1`   (or `path1, pathX` whatever)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crude, but it works:

```
---
- name: Fix line
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: get line from file
    command: grep '^paths = ' file
    register: grep
    failed_when: false

  - name: Add line if not present
    lineinfile:
      path: file
      state: present
      line: "paths = pathX"
    when: grep.rc != 0

  - name: Ensure pathX is in line
    lineinfile:
      path: file
      regexp: '^paths = path1'
      state: present
      line: "paths = path1, pathX"
    when: "'paths = path1' in grep.stdout"

  - name: Ensure path1 is in line
    lineinfile:
      path: file
      regexp: '^paths = pathX'
      state: present
      line: "paths = pathX, path1"
    when: "'paths = pathX' in grep.stdout"
```

You don't have to do everything in a single task.

Comment: I know ;), but I wanted to learn how negative lookahead regex works and could (or not) resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55660479/3779655) handling the case with multiple items better:

```yaml
- name: Fix line
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    path: file
    item: pathX
  tasks:
    - name: Get line from
      command: "grep '^paths = ' {{ path }}"
      register: grep
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: false
    - name: Add line if not present
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ path }}"
        line: 'paths = "{{ item }}"'
      register: lineadd
      when: grep.rc != 0
    # WARNING does not handle substring items correctly:
    # "foo" will not be added when "afoob" already exists as ("foo" in "afoob") evaluates to true.
    - name: Add item if not present
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ path }}"
        regexp: '^paths = "(?P<olditems>[^"]*)"'
        line: 'paths = "\g<olditems>{{ ","+item if item not in grep.stdout else "" }}"'
        backrefs: yes
      when: lineadd.changed == False
```